# include layout into preference

Tags: android, layout, preference

I have a layout for the header and the footer. And I also have a preference.xml layout. What I want to do right now is I want to include the normal layout into the preference.xml

Any idea on how to include the normal xml layout into the preference.xml layout ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `include` you can add a layout to other layouts:

**Example:**

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/include1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/normal_layout" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  tag to include layouts in xml file.

```
<include
android:id="@+id/header_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
layout="@layout/normal_layout" />
```